# Does any extra configuration need to be done for IActionContextAccessor with ASP.NET Core 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid-connect

So, I am trying to migrate my ASP.NET Core project to 3.0, and am having some breaking changes. I am trying to use OpenID Connect with AWS Cognito to authenticate users to the web application. Worked fine in my 2.2 project, but no longer works with 3.0 (preview 9).

This is the error I receive:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.ArgumentNullException: context (Parameter 'Value cannot be null or empty.')
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.UrlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(ActionContext context)
```

It seems as though my `IActionContextAccessor` is now `null` when trying set this up.

`IActionContextAccessor` is injected in an `AuthenticationBuilder` function.

I am not sure what might be the issue.

In my startup.cs in the Configure function I have the following:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UsePathBase("/");

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/500/");
            }

            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/error/{0}/");
            app.UseAuthentication();

            if (env.IsProduction())
            {
                app.Use((context, next) =>
                {
                    // https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/757
                    context.Request.Scheme = "https";
                    return next();
                });
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            //app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Endpoints}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

I have also included this in my `.csproj`: 
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="3.0.0-preview9.19424.4" />`
Is there some weird thing I'm now missing?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Hi, @MikeBrunner I looked back at my working solution (I've since updated the nuget package to version 3.1.2. 
But, I found [this section of the Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure) helpful.

I know I needed to make sure that `app.UseAuthentication()` was done **before** `app.UseAuthorization()`